# PSoC PWM for driving LED

Tags: led, psoc

I'm trying to implement an LED driver and I found the next circuit in PSoC's Guide on how to use the GPIOs.

Thing is I don't get if it's a must to include the R3 resistor and the Q2 transistor or if it's enough configuring the Pin_4 as Strong Drive??

thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the R_2 value is large enough that it limits the current through the LED to a value that is within spec for the GPIO on the MCU **and** the VDD powering the LED is the same voltage level as the MCU GPIO power rail then you can directly drive the LED R_2 from the GPIO pin.

You would need the transistor and the R_3 resistor if:

1. The LED power rail is a higher voltage than the MCU GPIO power rail such as 9V, 12V etc.
2. The LED needs much higher current through it to illuminate it to the brightness desired.